# Mono - Building/running Microsoft Compact Framework applications under Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to build a .NET project on Mono.

```
efulmer:[~/projects/MyApp]$ msbuild MyApp.csproj 
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.0.0 ( Mon Aug 14 21:03:24 UTC 2017) for Mono
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 10/11/2017 3:46:23 PM.
Project "/home/efulmer/projects/MyApp/MyApp.csproj" on node 1 (default targets).
/home/efulmer/projects/MyApp/MyApp.csproj(161,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done Building Project "/home/efulmer/projects/MyApp/MyApp.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"/home/efulmer/projects/MyApp/MyApp.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
  /home/efulmer/projects/MyApp/MyApp.csproj(161,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.14
```

The line in question is `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)/Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" />`

The underlying problem is fairly obvious to me after some searching (missing .NET Compact Framework) but I'm not sure how to solve it, as I installed `mono-complete`. But I don't know how to solve it. Help appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to build for a Arm/x86 supported CF board/device, or just re-use existing non-GUI CF-based code to run on a *nix/macOS?

Comment: @SushiHangover The latter: trying to run an existing GUI-less CF app on *nix (specifically Ubuntu 16.04 here).

Comment: You can remove the MSBuild CF target and make sure that a  `<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` exists. That should get it at least compiling and producing code-related errors (depending upon what the code is referencing that only exists in CF, you could have a little or a lot of refactoring to do...)

Comment: As other comments indicated, you should port the CF project back to full .NET Framework, and then try on Mono. CF is Windows CE/Mobile specific, so it is meaningless to use that anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with case sensitivity. I had a similar problem with a program not finding `Microsoft.CSHARP.Targets`

It turns out that MSBuild provides a file called `Microsoft.CSharp.targets`

I created a symlink from `Microsoft.CSHARP.Targets` to `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` and that worked around the problem.